# Does abstraction have a relationship with the abstract key word in java?

Tags: java, abstraction

I learnt the concept of abstraction as:

> Reducing complexity by hiding unnecessary details.

Does this have a relationship with the abstract keyword in java?
I see that the abstract keyword is being used in methods in classes like this:

```
public abstract void printName();
```

Comment: Abstract members cannot contain implementation, like your code example does, just FYI.

Comment: Edited my code, was a bit busy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it does not.** Those are two different things.

In Java, the `abstract` is a language keyword, which can only be placed on methods in classes also marked `abstract`. If you do this, then such class cannot be instantiated directly (you cannot create a new instance of it using `new`) and the `abstract` method must not have implementation. If you wish to provide the implementation, you need to **extend** the `abstract` class by a non-abstract one, where you will be forced by the compiler to provide implementations for all the `abstract` methods the parent `abstract` class defines. It is a keyword directly related to OOP and [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), making it possible to choose a valid implementation e.g. during runtime.

The same keyword is also adapted by several other OOP languages, such as [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) or [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract). On the other hand, for example C++ does not have the `abstract` keyword and to represent the same concept uses [pure virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) (but it's still the same thing - parent class defining a method for which children must provide implementation).

The other abstraction of hiding implementation details is a general programming concept, revolving around the idea that when you call some code, you shouldn't rely on its inner workings, but on the provided API (e.g. method signature).

Given an example function to add two numbers:

```
public class Calculator {

    public int addInts(int left, int right) {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

you are inherently hiding the implementation detail that adding two numbers requires placing the plus (`+`) symbol between them. Thanks to this, some other code may use your method without such knowledge:

```
int result = Calculator.addInts(10, 15);
```

However silly this example is regarding addition, introduction e.g. of a more complicated function, such as `sqrt` for square root calculation, simplifies callers of your `sqrt` method which no longer need to focus on the inner working of how a square root is calculated. Also, given a stable definition of your API (in methods analogy the input and output arguments), you could perhaps completely rework the implementation of your `sqrt` method. Given the calculation would still be correct, the algorithm could suddenly be 10 times faster and the consumers of the `sqrt` method would automatically benefit from this, without having to change anything (as long as the consumers of the method relied only on its input and output arguments semantics and not on the method's inner workings).

And of course, abstraction can be applied on entire layers of software. Perhaps you have some method which loads users:

```
List<User> loadUsers() {
   // ...
}
```

which internally calls a database by running a SQL statement. By introducing this method, you added a level of abstraction to shield other layers of your application from interacting with SQL directly and instead put the SQL into this method. Thanks to this you could in the future decide to store the users in a completely different way, and the users of the `loadUsers` method wouldn't be bothered by it at all, since they didn't know anything about a SQL database in the first place.

Comment: The first paragraph is pretty unclear.  Are you saying that 'pure virtual functions' are inherently different from abstract methods in Java? note: all methods defined in interfaces are implicitly abstract unless otherwise declared.

Comment: @JimmyJanes, I said nothing like that. I said that the `abstract` keyword does not exist in C++, it instead uses a concept called pure virtual functions. But considering the C++ page I linked to is about abstract classes, I thought it was pretty obvious it is still the same concept. I will reword the first paragraph.

Comment: @JimmyJames reworded the first paragraph. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is somewhat related, but not as you think:

- An `abstract` class is a class that cannot be instantiated, and an `abstract` method is a method that has no implementation. The principle is that an abstract class needs to be specialized by a class that implements its abstract methods, before it can be used to really create objects.

  So it's not h*iding unnecessary details*, but not providing them at all.  On the other hand, it is really about simplifying the idea one can have about the class and therefore contributes to reduce complexity.
- The objective of *Reducing complexity by hiding unnecessary details* can also be achieved with `interface`. In an interface, the details are very effectively hidden: how the interface is implemented is not visible, unless you know the class implementing it.  It is again forcing to keep a simpflified view on what an interface is and reduce the complexity by keep the ideas to be implemented as simple as possible.
- Hiding in Java is done using accessibility keywords such as `public`, `protected` and `private`.  It's not really hiding the details from you, since you can read them in the source code.  But it hides these details from other classes, that just are not allowed to rely on the details. This is another significant and very effective way to reduce complexity.

Comment: Yes, abstraction has as much to do with `abstract` as interfaces with `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Some of the other answers are down too deep in the details of what `abstract` does in Java to get at the underlying concept that the term comes from and its essential purpose.

Ironically, that's an example of not seeing the forest for the trees, i.e. lack of abstraction.

Here's a more relevant definition of *abstraction* from Oxford Languages:

> 1. the quality of dealing with ideas rather than events.
>    "topics will vary in degrees of abstraction"
> 2. freedom from representational qualities in art.

**The point of abstraction** in programming (or engineering or math) is to be able to think in terms of an understandable high level concept rather than all the details of the specific one and how it happens to be built. <== *The "hiding details" point comes in here but it must support a higher level, simpler mental concept to count as abstraction. Ignoring 90% of the trees would reduce detail but isn't an abstraction.*

So if you have a graphical "shape" abstraction you can think in terms of the "shape" concept without regard to its rendering algorithm, whether it uses a CPU or GPU to render, or even whether it's an ellipse, rectangle, polygon, or other shape.

A `printName()` method defines how you can ask an object to print its name without regard to whether the name is in a database, computed from fields in memory, localized to the language of the person running the app, cached, or made up from a sequence counter (gensym).

It lets you think in terms of *printing a name* without having to read, understand, and keep in mind all the steps inside a `printName()` method while you're thinking about all the other parts of the program you're juggling at the moment. When you sit down to optimize its source code, *then* you dive inside that abstraction (and shouldn't need to keep in mind how all its callers work). Otherwise you can ignore those details and use precious short term memory for other details.

Sometimes an abstraction is "leaky", which means its details leak out and you can't ignore them. This happens often for poorly conceived abstractions.

I once handed off a program to another developer who (as I later discovered by reading the code) thought of each function as just a sequence of statements, editable in any old way without regard to a named abstraction. That leads to chaos, "spaghetti code," with no way to think in terms of higher level concepts.

An `abstract` class defines an abstraction (or concept) such as a graphical shape, a GUI widget, an employee record, or whatever, along with some protocol and some shared parts like perhaps common fields or factory methods. The difference between an *abstract class* and an *interface* in Java is just a detail to do with subclassing and not salient to the matter of abstraction.

An `abstract` `printName()` method defines the abstraction of a method you can call to print the name of any object of the given abstract class's subclasses (or that implements the given interface). The abstract method defines the method name, parameters, output, exceptions, and any side effects, in other words the semantics of that method.

The `abstract` keyword gets Java to support building an abstract class or method. Java doesn't know about our underlying conceptual abstractions, just the language parts like the requirement to implement abstract methods to make a subclass that you can instantiate.

Comment: I disagree with this. It seems convenient that those two would be the same, since they sound the same on the paper. But the `abstract` keyword chosen by a few languages is merely a compile time indicator for the language's possibilities. In the same same you could argument that the `public` keyword has the same relationship to abstraction as the `abstract` keyword does.

Comment: @Andy That makes sense. My perspective comes from knowing that the keyword came from the idea of "abstract data types" and the engineering goal of abstracting _what_ an object does from _how_ it works. It was a huge step to help tame the "software crisis" of complexity by working at a higher level and by enabling changing an object's implementation without having to fixup everything that uses it. The purpose of that keyword in Java is to support this kind of design abstraction although the Java language doesn't operate at that level.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes and members are one way of achieving polymorphism in Java and other similar object oriented languages. Polymorphism is at the root of creating abstractions. Polymorphism allows many kinds of objects to be treated the same way, while the implementations remain hidden from those using the objects. This certainly "reduces complexity by hiding unnecessary details."

Interfaces in Java-like languages are really just syntactic sugar for abstract classes that only contain abstract members, if we exclude default methods for a moment.

The abstract keyword tells the compiler that a child class will provide the implementation. The child class is a specialization of the parent. The signature of abstract members is known to the parent and those using an object cast to the parent type. The implementation details of those abstract members is known only to the child class.

The `abstract` keyword is the language construct that ties the concept of "software abstractions" to the compiler mechanisms that allow us to write code abstract code.

Answer (score -2):

Of course they are related. Abstract methods, together with abstract classes and interfaces, hide the implementation from the client. At this level you no longer care about how something was implemented, but only what it does and what's its result.

Now, how this is used in OOP and what you gain from it is a different story. Abstraction is never an end in itself.